# MySQL query aggregate MAX and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to get value from a subquery in where inside select?

stop_link Table

```
id | duid | domain_id 
1  | 1    | 1
2  | 2    | 1
3  | 1    | 2
4  | 2    | 2
5  | 3    | 1
```

Result that I want (assume domain_id = 2)

```
duid    | domain_id 
3       | 2
```

Query (not working):

```
INSERT INTO stop_link (
              duid,

              domain_id) 
SELECT
  IFNULL(MAX(sl.duid), 0) + 1 AS duid,
  sl.domain_id 
FROM
  stop_link sl
WHERE sl.domain_id = (SELECT sd.id FROM stop_domain sd LIMIT 1)
```

Query working but I wish to avoid the Set Variable:

```
SET @domain_id = (SELECT sd.id FROM stop_domain sd LIMIT 1);
SELECT
  IFNULL(MAX(sl.duid), 0) + 1 AS duid
  , @domain_id
FROM
  stop_link sl
WHERE sl.domain_id = @domain_id;
```

Comment: What is the logic for the result that you want?

Comment: explain your logic to get desired result

Comment: I think all you need to do is insert a `GROUP BY domain_id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using this select as Insert to create a new record and the value duid is a 2nd unique id related to domain_id.

Comment: @maraca group by remove the error but it give a empty result back

Comment: This should only happen if the sub-query returns a number that doesn't exist in the table, if you use limit you maybe wanna use it together with order by.

Comment: @maraca probably now is more clear, I have add the full usage of the query

Comment: If there is more than one entry in stop_domain I would recommend to add order by or where-clause to the subquery to ensure you get the right number and see if still nothing is inserted with group by. Insert doesn't return anything, so maybe you missed it? Or you need to commit?

Comment: @maraca I have updated the Question with a working example that uses SET now it should be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
/*Your example Table*/

DECLARE @T  
TABLE(ID INT,duid INT,domain_id INT)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(1 , 1    , 1 ),
(2  , 2    , 1),
(3  , 1    , 2),
(4  , 2    , 2),
(5  , 3    , 1)

--The query
SELECT domain_id,Isnull(max(duid),0)+1 [newId]
FROM @T
GROUP BY domain_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed answer based on new info from the comments.  It sounds like you've got `only_full_group_by` enabled in your `sql_mode`.  Your query would probably work with that disabled, but the following may also work for you:

```
INSERT INTO stop_link (
              duid,

              domain_id) 

SELECT
  IFNULL(MAX(sl.duid), 0) + 1 AS duid,
  sl.domain_id 
FROM
  stop_link sl
WHERE sl.domain_id = (SELECT sd.id FROM stop_domain sd LIMIT 1)
-- ORDER by sl.domain_id DESC LIMIT 1 # Removed in favor of the following line
GROUP BY sl.domain_id HAVING MAX(sl.id)
;
```

Note that the subquery may not be returning the `stop_domain.id` that you want it to be -- you might have intended to select MAX(sd.id), or perhaps you just removed a `WHERE sd.url='foo'` for clarity's sake.

Comment: @A C this query is the same as mine, the column name is id in the stop_domain table

Comment: Can you give the info on that table (columns, in particular) then?  And about how exactly it's not working (throwing error, unexpected result, etc) ?

Comment: The table stop_domain has id and domain_url. The error is: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column '.sl.domain_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Is the `SELECT sd.id FROM stop_domain sd LIMIT 1` subquery intended to get the max or anything?  As it stands, it may just return random id...

Comment: Do you need `only_full_group_by` enabled?  I think your original query would work without that.  Have you tried replacing your `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` with `GROUP BY sl.domain_id HAVING MAX(sl.id)` ?

Answer (score 0):

No need of `max()`:

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(sl.duid, 0) + 1 AS duid,
  sl.domain_id 
FROM
  stop_link sl
WHERE sl.domain_id = (SELECT sd.id FROM stop_domain sd LIMIT 1)
ORDER by sl.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Surely max() is needed as we must know the highest value of duid in combination with domain_id

Comment: have you tried it, you are using `limit 1` to achieve this with `order by DESC`. This should be enough